# How to "power nap" an application on Mac OS

Tags: macos

I saw that a functionnality called "Power nap" that permit OSX to do some stuff while being in sleep mode.
My question is: It is possible to "Power nap" my own app ?

Comment: The official [Power Nap support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204032) makes no mention of third-parties being allowed to do anything.

Comment: Are you trying to make your app sleep or keep it from sleeping?

Comment: I try to make the app continuing during sleep

Comment: Oh, I see. You want your app to continue working in the background even while the computer is in sleep mode. OK, now I understand you.